# Possible To Import A Module Once And Have Method Available To Multiple Modules With Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, node-modules

I am trying to learn how to use modules with webpack. I believe I now understand that if a module calls a method from a different module it must be imported.

What I do not understand is, what do I do in a situation where multiple modules make a call to a method defined in another module?

Is the proper way to handle this scenario to import the required modules into each js module file?

**isObject.js**

```
const isObject = (a) => (!!a) && (a.constructor === Object);

export {isObject}
```

**findNote.js**

```
import {isObject} from './isObject';

const findNote = ( notes, id ) => {
    return isObject( notes.findIndex(function( note ){
        return note.id === id;
    }) );
}

export {findNote}
```

**filterNotes.js**

```
import {isObject} from './isObject';

const filterNotes = ( notes, filter ) => {
    return isObject( notes.filter(function( note ){
        return note.title.toLowerCase().includes( filter.toLowerCase() ) );
    });
}

export {filterNotes}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are newcomer.

`Node.js` would [cache modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching). Every modules would just be loaded once

Comment: Okay, so every module is only loaded once. I notice that if my module makes a call to a method that I have to import that it MUST be imported into each module that is making the call otherwise after webpack is run the code fails. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I cannot understand very well. Can you make a example project that we can talk base on it ?

Answer (score 0):

webpack is a script bundler. It has a notion of 'entry points' and builds one or more script bundle(s) for each entrypoint.

Therefore if you make `findNote.js` to be an entry point or if there is an existing entry point that imports (directly or indirectly) `findNote.js`, then all dependencies including `isObject.js` will be included into this bundle.

Same story for `filterNotes.js`. If you make it to be another entry point then its code and its dependencies including `isObject.js` will be included into another bundle for that entry point.

So `isObject.js` will be included into several bundles. This can be prevented using some optimisation.

Comment: So, what happens is say a file app.js is the entry point, and app.js imports all 3 of the JS modules. Because findNote.js and filterNotes.js BOTH import isObject.js is all of that code duplicated in the final bundle?

Comment: @mcbeav The 4 modules being app.js, findNote.js, filterNotes.js and isObject.js will be included once into the bundle.